# NOT NULL by itself outputs correctly. Adding NOT NULL, AND and OR outputs nulls

Tags: sql

How does one combine the `NOT NULL` with the `AND` and `OR`?

The output of this query is correct. It outputs the non nulls from the column rate_spread :

```
SELECT action_taken, action_taken_name, applicant_ethnicity, 
       applicant_ethnicity_name, applicant_income_000s, county_name, 
       loan_amount_000s, rate_spread
FROM usa_cfpb_hmda.2007

WHERE rate_spread is NOT NULL
LIMIT 10
```

[image]

However, when a constraint is added, `Not Null`  no longer works. However the `OR` does work.  As in this example:

```
SELECT action_taken, action_taken_name, 
       applicant_ethnicity, applicant_ethnicity_name, 
       applicant_income_000s, county_name, loan_amount_000s, 
       rate_spread
FROM usa_cfpb_hmda.2007

where rate_spread is NOT NULL
     and action_taken = 1
     OR action_taken = 6
```

limit 10

[image]

Comment: This is nothing to do with the `NOT NULL` statement, it's because you've mixed AND and OR. You have to wrap brackets around conditions you want to link together to specify what you mean, same as in any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prioritize your logic (i.e. use parenthesis) :

```
where rate_spread is not null and 
     (action_taken = 1 or action_taken = 6);
```

Comment: Making me delete my identical answer by typing faster than me = +1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to group your conditions with parenthesis

```
SELECT action_taken, action_taken_name, 
       applicant_ethnicity, applicant_ethnicity_name, 
       applicant_income_000s, county_name, loan_amount_000s, 
       rate_spread
FROM usa_cfpb_hmda.2007

where rate_spread is NOT NULL
     and (action_taken = 1
     OR action_taken = 6)
```

so that SQL interprets the condition as: either in action_taken = 1 or action_taken = 6 AND also rate_spread is not null.